# Trouble using a parameter in a variable SQL

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am still fairly new to using SQL, so anything will help. My goal right is to add a parameter to allow the user to filter out the results based on a single column. I am working in SSRS and the way my tables are laid out there is one table that has a column with user created labels for columns in other tables. I am dynamically searching for the column name I need and then using this to pull the information I need off a second table. However, the trouble comes when I want to add a parameter to filter the results.

```
DECLARE @Root varchar(max);
DECLARE @Command varchar(max);
SET @Root=(SELECT ColumnName FROM FirstTable WHERE USER_LABEL = 'Results')
SET @Command = 'SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN 
      '+@Root+' IS NULL THEN ''Null''
    ELSE
      '+@Root+'
  END AS "Result"
  ,COUNT(*) AS "Number"
  ,CAST(ROUND(COUNT(*)*100.0/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SecondTable),1) AS DECIMAL(4,1)) AS "Percentage"
FROM SecondTable
```

From what I understand, SSRS helps you out when creating parameters, and the following line looks like the only thing I have to do to create the parameter.

```
WHERE Filter = @filt
```

However, I get an error stating I "Must declare the scalar variable '@filt'." Is there a work around for this? It looks like it wants me to declare the @filt as a variable within the string variable it is located.

```
GROUP BY '+@Root+''
EXEC(@Command)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you need to declare the variable and then append it to the string for this to work.

```
  DECLARE @filt varchar(max) --pick correct length and 
                             --add to the rest of your variable declarations
```

Then append the variable to the end of your command:

```
  'WHERE Filter =' + @filt + ' GROUP BY '+@Root
```

You can then use SSRS to pass the value of @filt into the stored proc.

Comment: I'm trying to do it that way, but it's not getting any results. Normally in SSRS, a window will popup to create the parameter automatically when the query is run in Query Designer. However, nothing popups. Do I have to manually create the parameter?

Comment: You should create a stored proc and call it from SSRS.  That should get the parameter to show in SSRS, so that you can assign a value to it.

Comment: I also found this link that discusses the topic:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f7b85430-66f3-4932-a69c-3e41ddee4f3a/how-to-pass-report-parameters-to-stored-procedure-in-report-builder-30?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: Thank you! You helped a lot!